# How many simultaneous coin tosses until both coins have been heads? Finding a relevant distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

Consider the following problem.

> **Problem**
>     Take two fair coins, A and B. A "round" is when both coins are tossed at the same time.
>     What is the expected number of rounds until both coins have independently been heads at some point?

For example, the sequences $((H, T), (H, H))$ and $((H, T), (T, T), (T, H))$ would satisfy the condition.
The coins don't have to be heads at the same time and coins can be heads multiple times; all that matters is that they
have both been heads at some point.

I already know how to solve this problem: the answer is $\frac{8}{3}$. (See below if you're interested.)

> **Solution**
>     Let $f(a, b)$ be the expected number of tosses that still need to be done, where $a$ is $T$ ("true") if A has been
>     heads at some point and $a$ is $F$ ("false") otherwise; and similarly so for $b$.
>     The challenge is to find out what $f(F, F)$ is.
>
> Trivially $f(T, T) = 0$ because at that point we have achieved the goal.
>     More interestingly, however,
>       \begin{align*}
>     f(T, F)
>         &= 1 + \frac{1}{2} f(T, F) + \frac{1}{2} f(T, T) \\
>         &= 1 + \frac{1}{2} f(T, F)
> \end{align*}
>     because we always take one round, and on top of that there is a 50% chance that B is heads in which case we're done,
>     and a 50% chance that we did not make progress.
>     Solve for $f(T, F)$ to find $f(T, F) = 2$.
>     Similarly, because A and B are identical coins, $f(F, T) = 2$.
>
> Next, observe that
>       \begin{align*}
>     f(F, F)
>         &= 1
>          + \frac{1}{4} f(F, F)
>          + \frac{1}{4} f(F, T)
>          + \frac{1}{4} f(T, F)
>          + \frac{1}{4} f(T, T) \\
>         &= 1
>          + \frac{1}{4} f(F, F)
>          + \frac{2}{4}
>          + \frac{2}{4}
>          + \frac{0}{4} \\
>         &= 2 + \frac{1}{4} f(F, F).
> \end{align*}
>     Solve for $f(F, F)$ to find $f(F, F) = \frac{8}{3}$.

### Question

My question, instead, is *what kind of distribution is this*?
In particular, what distribution is this if we generalise the number of coins to any positive integer $n$?
I'm writing my thesis and because I'm not working in the field of statistics I want to refer to an existing body of work
instead of introducing the maths myself.
I looked at the [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution),
[multivariate hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution),
and many more, but none seem to describe my problem here.

Is there any distribution that describes the expected number of multi-variate categorical Bernoulli trials until all
categories (each with one instance) have been satisfied, without replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can model this distribution as the maximum of $n$ geometric distributions.
Let $X$ be the random variable that counts the number of coin flips until a coin comes up heads, and say the coin comes up heads with probability $p$.
Then

$$\Bbb P(X=k)=(1-p^{k-1})p$$

You'd want to look for the distribution of

$$Y_n = \max_{i=1,\dots,n} X_i,$$

where $X_i\sim X$.
I'm not sure if this already has a name, but at least you can speak of it in terms of already known constructs (geometric distributions).

---

We have

$$\begin{align}
\Bbb P(Y_n \leqslant k)
&=
\Bbb P(X_1 \leqslant k)^n
\\&=
{\left(1-(1-p)^k\right)}^n
\end{align}$$